# Async method never returns

Tags: c#, windows-8, task-parallel-library, deadlock, async-await

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WinRT: Loading static data with GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235085/winrt-loading-static-data-with-getfilefromapplicationuriasync)

The following code in my application is called, but it never returns, or throws an exception:

```
public async Task Load()
{
    ...
    StorageFile file = 
      await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///" + name));
    ...
}
```

This is how I call the method:

```
x.Load().Wait();
```

Why does the awaited method `GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync()` never return?

Comment: ask for `Result` on Task<T> . `public async Task<WhateverYourreturning> Load(){...}`. and in the calling method. `var result = x.Load().Result; `

Comment: thanks, but I am not returning anything

Comment: see if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235085/winrt-loading-static-data-with-getfilefromapplicationuriasync

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you (synchronously) block on asynchronous code, you [run into a deadlock problem](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Follow these best practices:

1. Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` whenever possible in your library methods (e.g., `Load`).
2. Use `async` all the way down; don't block on `async` code.

In your case, it sounds like `Load` may be called as part of startup. This is a bit tricky to do asynchronously (since constructors may not be `async`). However, you should be able to get it to work by utilizing [asynchronous lazy initialization](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html).