# WinRT App hangs when BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream) is called

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-async

I have the following method where I pass a InMemoryRandomAccessStream loaded with JPEG data:

```
private async Task<byte[]> GetDataAsync(IRandomAccessStream stream)
{
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

    BitmapFrame frame = await decoder.GetFrameAsync(0);

    BitmapTransform transform = new BitmapTransform()
    {
        ScaledWidth = decoder.PixelWidth,
        ScaledHeight = decoder.PixelHeight
    };

    PixelDataProvider pixelData = await frame.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, transform, ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);

    return pixelData.DetachPixelData();
}
```

This method hangs all the time except if I put a breakpoint to the first line and step over each line. I tried to use different JPEG images, modify the parameters of "GetPixelDataAsync" and temporary insert "await Task.Delay(...)" between lines, but nothing helps. The App performs a lot of other time consuming asynchronous operations and works fine except for this part. It is unclear why setting a breakpoint (except that it gives some time delay) makes it work.

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: could you show how you call this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess in the wild, but I had the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235085/winrt-loading-static-data-with-getfilefromapplicationuriasync).

I think you call this async method from a sync context like:

```
private void ButtonClick(...) 
{
  var bytes = GetDataAsync(...);
}
```

This will cause your application to run in the UI Thread which causes a deadlock. Either make the calling method async, too, which will work or use ConfigureAwait(false):

```
private async Task<byte[]> GetDataAsync(IRandomAccessStream stream)
{
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

    BitmapFrame frame = await decoder.GetFrameAsync(0).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

    BitmapTransform transform = new BitmapTransform()
    {
        ScaledWidth = decoder.PixelWidth,
        ScaledHeight = decoder.PixelHeight
    };

    PixelDataProvider pixelData = await frame.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, transform, ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

    return pixelData.DetachPixelData();
}
```

Maybe take a look here at this very nice [explanation](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.de/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) of using async/await and getting deadlocks.

Comment: I went with a WritableBitmap approach instead. However, UI deadlock problem altogether with ConfigureAwait(false) seems as a reasonable solution. Thank You, Raubi!

Comment: Didn't work for me.  Still hanging with the original OP scenario.

Comment: `explanation` link is now dead. Anyone know where to get a new link. Or even better, put the explanation as part of the answer?