# Getting a list of files using C# (Windows-Store App).Trouble with a function

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am trying to write a function that will return a list of files. So here is a source code:

```
public async IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> GetFiles()
    {
        StorageFolder folder = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("folder N1");
        if (folder != null)
        {
            IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fList = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
            return fList;
        }
    }
```

But why it is not work? The error message is "Can't convert IReadOnlyList to StorageFile". What's wrong? My fList variable has the same type as in a header of the function.

Comment: How about using `var` instead of `IReadOnlyList<StorageFile>`. Let the compiler set the correct type.

Answer (score 3):

Asynchronous method returns `Task<T>`, so change your function like this.

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<StorageFile>> GetFiles()
{
    StorageFolder folder = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("folder N1");
    if (folder != null)
         return await folder.GetFilesAsync();
    else
         return null;
}
```

[GetFilesAsync stops working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930113/getfilesasync-stops-working)

Comment: How to extract IReadOnlyList from task? I need IReadOnlyList as output of this function.

Comment: You don't have to extract from task, use method like `var Files = await GetFiles();`, `Files` will be `IReadOnlyList<StorageFile>`, did you check [GetFilesAsync stops working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930113/getfilesasync-stops-working) ?

Answer (score 2):

As @Xyroid said, you need use Task> as return type, because the return type of async method must be void, Task or Task. With the code @Xyroid posted. You can get files like this:

```
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await GetFiles();
int count = fileList.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list 'fList' is using StorageFile as its type - it should be using type IReadOnlyList. Try  the following:

```
List<IReadOnlyList> fList = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
```

as change the return type of your method:

```
public async List<IReadOnlyList> GetFiles()
{
    ...
}
```